# Why do the XGBoost predicted probabilities of my test and validation sets look well calibrated but not for my training set?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, boosting, calibration

I am using an XGBoost classifier to predict propensity to buy. After drawing a calibration curve to check how well the classification probabilities (predict_proba) produced are vs actual experience, I noticed that it looks well calibrated (close to diagonal line) for my test and even validation data sets but produces a "sigmoid" shaped curve (actual lower for bins with low predicted probabilities and actual higher for bins with high predicted probabilities) for the training set. I do not understand why this is the case and might be misunderstanding XGBoost's hyperparameters or functionality. Any explanation would be appreciated.

I used my test set to do limited tuning on the model's hyper-parameters. I also used sklearn's train_test_split to do a stratified (tested without the stratify argument as well to check if this causes sampling bias) split 65:35 between train and test and I also kept an out-of-time data set for validation.

```
XGBClassifier(learning_rate =0.05, n_estimators=500, max_depth=8, min_child_weight=3, gamma=0.1, subsample=0.6, reg_lambda = 2, reg_alpha=1, colsample_bytree=0.6, objective= 'binary:logistic',  scale_pos_weight=1, seed=21)
```

[image: Calibration curve]

Comment: +1, this is a good question. The approximate answer is that we are "overfitting our training set" so any claims about generalisable performance based on the training set behaviour is bogus, we/the classifier is "over-confident" so to speak. The sigmoid seen is exactly this "overconfidece" where for the "somewhat unlikely" events we claim they are "very unlikely" and for "somewhat likely" events we claim they are "very likely". Exactly because we do not overfit the test set we escape the sigmoid. (Pretty good performance to be honest.)

Comment: Thanks usεr11852 for the intuitive explanation, seems obvious now. My flawed reasoning was that the over-fitting on the training set should have resulted in a calibration close to the diagonal for the training set

Comment: Cool. I will try to expand on this a bit and write it down as an answer later today.